# You must supply a layout_width attribute

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following XML file being inflated and I don't know why I'm getting an error. Here is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/transitionForm"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/backgroundcolor"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<include
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/assistekborders" />

<include
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/assistek_pro_borderwidgets" />

<include
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/assistek_pro_questionlabels" />

<include
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/assistek_pro_practicesessionwidgets" />

<include
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/assistek_pro_progress" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/svPRORGWidgets"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ImageBottom"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lblSubQuestionText"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30px"
    android:layout_marginRight="50px"
    android:layout_marginTop="30px"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lblQuestionNumber"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants" >
    <!-- 
    <TableLayout 
      android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dip" >
     -->
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </RadioGroup>
     <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </RadioGroup>
    <!-- 
    </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
     -->
</ScrollView>
```

Here is the logcat error.  I don't see what the issue is - all my elements have a layout_width attribute.

```
04-15 21:02:31.800: E/AndroidRuntime(3577): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-15 21:02:31.800: E/AndroidRuntime(3577): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start   activity ComponentInfo{com.assistek.ediary/com.assistek.ediary.RadioGroupQuestionnaire}:   java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #46: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
04-15 21:02:31.800: E/AndroidRuntime(3577):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
04-15 21:02:31.800: E/AndroidRuntime(3577):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
04-15 21:02:31.800: E/AndroidRuntime(3577):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
```

Comment: Check that all those included layouts are properly formed with `android:layout_width` attributes where required. Run the Android lint tool to help track down the problem.

Comment: Lint turned up the answer that banannn provided as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ScrollView can have only one child.

Try put your RadioGroup inside LinearLayout or RelativeLayout.

Comment: Thanks - that was the problem!